# why does cycling kill training and running shoes so quickly?

Tags: shoes

If I ride in running shoes or training shoes, why do the soles come away from the uppers at the toe end so spectacularly? Are cycling shoes proper constructed differently to stop this happening?

Comment: Cycling shoes are very different indeed. They have rigid soles. I don't know why your running shoes are getting so torn up.

Comment: Proper cycling shoes can last tens of thousands of kilometers without significant wear.

Comment: @Adam only for a very narrow definition of cycling shoes. Mountain or touring SPDs are much more like trainers (and mine eventually fail in the same way)

Comment: @ChrisH I have touring SPDs. The soles aren't as rigid as my road shoes, but they're not *not* rigid.

Comment: @AdamRice my current ones are slightly more flexible than my softest hiking boots, my previous ones closer to trainers (except very near the cleat of course).  But I do choose them for walking as well as riding.  I've come across some stiffer touring shoes but didn't think I'd get on with them

Answer (score 4):

Running shoes are generally only designed for running and the glue between soles/uppers seems to be very weak when the shoe is subjected to forces in a different direction.

At the top of the pedal stroke as you begin to press down you are transmitting force in the opposite direction to what you find when running.

You can find exactly the same effect when you use running shoes for other sports (such as table tennis or badminton) that have a lot of side to side movement.

Comment: Funnily enough I bought my running shoes more for badminton (which also means I bought them a good few years ago based on when I changed jobs & stopped playing). They've done well for that, MTB, and even a little (road) running

Answer (score 2):

The answer also depends on the kind of pedals you are using, some are harder on soles than others. Among the flat pedals, there are some that are very smooth and are likely to be gentle on the soles (but they can be very slippery), or if you need some lateral grip the contact point between the pedal and the sole is very small (usually by adding "spikes" on the pedal). Running shoes are more than probably not designed to sustain concentrated shear.

```
Are cycling shoes proper constructed differently to stop this happening?
```

There are two kinds of cycling shoes: the ones for clipless pedals, and the ones for flat pedals.

Most cycling enthusiasts use clipless/automatic pedals, where the pedal has a receiver in which a cleat (metal part that you screw into the sole) will block itself. The contact between the shoe and the pedal is then metal against metal, and the cleats are removable if they were to be worn before something else in the shoe. In these conditions, the it's not the wear between the shoe and the pedal that will define how long the shoe will last.

There are also cycling shoes for flat pedals (mostly for MTBs). I don't know how those compare compared to running shoes, but I would assume that the design specifications are more suited to biking that to running.

Comment: Flatpedal shoes are much better for walking than clipless shoes. But of course there's some tradeoff: the tough sole still makes running a rather stompy affair.

Comment: I find that some flat pedals have somewhat-sharp teeth and will eat their way though a soft sole.  But that's with cheap foam-like soles - better harder rubber soles would cope much better.

Comment: @Criggie Interestingly, high-end mountain biking flat pedal shoes have a short lifetime due to the rubber used being soft for good grip. Replacing the shoes annually is nothing rare.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say you've been unlucky - here are some examples to demonstrate.

I've had two pairs of mountain/touring/commuting SPDs fail that way, but each pair lasted 15000--20000 km of riding and at least 1000 km of walking/jogging. They were Specialized Cadets, lace-ups styled rather like casual trainers, and with quite a flexible sole by bike shoes standards. In both cases the uppers were very shabby by that point, but I got a little more life out of them as reserves by gluing the sole back on around the toe.

My current pair (Giro Rumble) are probably going to fail in a similar way, by the heel glue failing.  As with the Cadets, these are clipped in when riding and I can pull up on the pedals with them, stressing the shoe more.  They've done 20000 km as well, again plus some hiking and even jogging.

Most of my actual mountain biking has been done in some cheap Hi-Tec cross-country running shoes.  They've probably done over 1000 km on the MTB without any signs of failure, though there's some damage to the soles from the metal edges of the pedal.

But I've seen that failure mode in shoes that have seen (little or) no bike use - the hiking boots I was wearing yesterday might have been ridden for a few 10s of km at most in several years, and I'm going to need to get the glue out for the join between sole and upper at the toes.